# Bash script to recursively traverse directories, compare and sync files

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a bash shell script to sync content on two different paths.

The algorithm I'm striving for consists of the following steps

1. given two full (as opposed to relative) paths
2. recursively compare files (whose filename optionally may have
   basename and suffix) in corresponding directories of both paths
3. if either corresponding directories or files are not present, then
   copy each file (from the path with the folder) to the other
   corresponding folder.

I've figured out steps 1 and 2 which are

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
# The extra space after is crucial
IFS=\

for old_file in `diff -rq old/ new/ | grep "^Files.*differ$" | sed 's/^Files \(.*\) and .* differ$/\1/'`
do
   mv $old_file $old_file.old
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use something like `rsync`, instead of writing something less capable on your own?

Comment: Self-study. Trying to learn how to write bash script. But this is not a homework.

Comment: That's fine - what is your exact problem with step 3?

Comment: I'm having difficulty coming up with the algorithm for step 3.

Comment: `grep` followed by `sed` is a waste of CPU cycles. Just use `sed -e '/pattern/s/from/to/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a similar algorithm in Java, which essentially boils down to this:

1. Retrieve a listing of directories A and B, e.g. `A.lst` and `B.lst`
2. Create the [*intersection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of both listings (e.g. `cat A.lst B.lst | sort | uniq -d`). This is the list of files you need to actually compare; you will also have to descend to any directories recursively.

   You may want to have a look at the conditional expressions supported by your shell (e.g. for [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)) or by the [`test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) command. I would also suggest using `cmp` instead of `diff`.

   Note: you need to consider what the proper action should be when you have a directory on one side and a file on the other with the same name.
3. Find the files that are only present in A (e.g. `cat A.lst B.lst B.lst | sort | uniq -u`) and copy them recursively (`cp -a`) to B.
4. Similarly, find the files that are only present in B and copy them recursively to A.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention a significant optimization: if you `sort` the file lists `A.lst` and `B.lst` beforehand, you can use [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) instead of `cat ... | sort | uniq ...` to perform the set operations:

- Intersection: `comm -12 A.sorted.lst B.sorted.lst`
- Files that exist only in A: `comm -23 A.sorted.lst B.sorted.lst`
- Files that exist only in B: `comm -13 A.sorted.lst B.sorted.lst`

Answer (score 0):

There exists a ready-made solution (shell script), based on **find** (also using the same idea as yours), to synchronize two directories: https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha.sh.

Documentation is here: https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha.sh/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md.

Cheers

Comment: This answer is fine. I vote Keep. You cannot expect this poster to identify and post the critical parts of a program that isn't theirs. Esp not when all they want to say is "Look, spare your work. This one over there is ready to use"